# Parametric plot

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I want to plot `x = u Cos[Phi] + v Cos[(u Phi)/v]` and `y = u Sin[Phi] - v Sin[(u Phi)/v]`in a parametric graph for `u = 3` and `v = 5`. This is my command:

```
ParametricPlot[{x, y} /. {u -> 3, v -> 5}, {Phi, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

I think it was supposed to show two circles and it's not.

Also, for the same u and v values, if the angular velocity of the inner circle about its own center is 0.1 rad/sec, and the time taken for an arbitrary initial
contact point to return to the same configuration.

Comment: [Definitely not a circle.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vSBCi.png)

Comment: Hmm that's what I thought too. But then the problem asks what are the radii for the inner and outer circles so I'm not sure

Answer (score 2):

```
p1 = ParametricPlot[{x, y} /. {u -> 3, v -> 5}, {Phi, 0, 10 \[Pi]}, 
PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
v=2;

p2 = ParametricPlot[{v Cos[u], v Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[1]]]
```

[image]

```
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

but do the Math by your self, because there are other circles

**Edit - some sources and infos:**

[Parametric Equations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParametricEquations.html)

[Natural Parametric Equations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalParametricEquations.html)

[Circle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle.html)

[How to | Plot Parametric Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/PlotParametricFunctions.html)

[How to | Create Plots](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CreatePlots.html)

Have Fun!

Comment: What do you mean other circles? And why did you use sin and cos to get the circle? I really don't get this